# How to write code for user control message box to display in web pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to show a user control message box which can be used for save success, save failure, success, Error, Information, warning , Update Success and Update failure.

I can use alert but I don't want to use alert in my program. Till now I am using alert to display message but it is old fashioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peasy, just go to http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation for a great demo of jQuery-UI dialog boxes, easy to use and don't look too bad either.

Simples

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ along with jQuery.
Specifically http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation as an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: That was such a coincidence!